# Font in SFML. Information is not displayed on the screen. Instead of information, a dot is displayed

Tags: c++, c, sfml, display

Font in SFML. Information is not displayed on the screen. Instead of information, a dot is displayed. I output both the text and the numerical value, but the dot is still displayed.

**Error or incorrectly written code in this section below:**

```
    sf::RenderWindow area(sf::VideoMode(960, 540), "Prog", sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Titlebar);

    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("Font/golos_text.ttf");

    char count[10];
    _itoa_s(this->saves->getMoney(), count, 10, 10); // Should turn (int) 20 into (char *) "20"

    sf::Text text(count, font, 20);
    text.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
    text.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);

    text.setString(count); // [1] If you print (int) count - a POINT is displayed at the coordinates 20x20
    /* text.setString("HALLO"); */ // [2] If you print char* "HALLO" - a POINT is displayed at the coordinates 20x20

    text.setPosition(20, 20);
    area.draw(text);
    area.display();
```

Comment: Obvious questions: does `loadFromFile` return `true`, and what kind of font is this `golos_text` font? Is it TrueType or a Bitmap font? If the latter, does it support character size 20?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you simply forgot to apply the font to `text`:

`text.setFont(font);`

SFML doesn't provide a default font, so this is a crucial step